# Wordpress plugin with multiple pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin and I'm a little confused by something. Basically, I have a menu on the Wordpress admin sidebar.

When you click on the menu, it takes you to the main page 'includes/main.php'. This works fine.

However, I have another page in the plugin folder 'includes/product.php'. When I click a button on the main page, I'd like to be able to send data to 'includes/product.php' and open that page as an admin page just like the main page, but I need to send data over when I click the button too.

I'm just not sure how to call the products.php page and have it as a Wordpress page that's part of the plugin, just like the main page. Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 1):

To use the wordpress framework in `product.php`, you have to include this page from your `main.php`. You could include it on the top of `main.php` and have an if statement that checks if there is post data, like this:

**main.php**

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    include 'product.php';
    // you can let product.php do the rest of the rendering
}
else{
    // render your page
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another option is creating a submenu.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page